# Compare two numbers read from a file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script that reads a file with a standard format where the 9th word is a number. I am trying to compare the number that is read from the file. I am able to read the line correctly and it works exactly as I want it to. But I get an error that says :

```
./age.sh: line 8: [: age: integer expression expected
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f $1 ] ;
then
    while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]]; do
        name=$( echo $LINE | cut -d " " -f1 -f2)
        ago=$( echo $LINE | cut -d " " -f9)     
        echo "$name ----- $age"
        if [ $ago -gt 30 ] ; then
            echo "You get a discount"
        fi
    done < $1
    else
        echo "No file found"
fi
```

Here is a sample input file

```
#FirstName LastName SuperheroName Powers Weapons City Enemy isOutOfEarth Age
Bruce Wayne Batman Martial_arts No_Guns Gowtham Joker No 31
Clark Kent Superman Extreme_strength None Metropolitan Lex_Luther Yes 32
Oliver Queen Green_arrow Accuracy Bow_and_Arrow Star_city Cupid No 30
```

Comment: apparently `$LINE`'s 9th field is not just an integer.

Comment: Does it print the error if only the 9th field is not a number? 
Or is it printing it in respect to the entire file?

Comment: Test it yourself: `[ 't' -gt 1 ] && echo "yes"` and `[ 3 -gt 1 ] && echo "yes"`.

Comment: I was also wondering why this is needed: `while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]]; do`. I used it because most of the other examples used it.

Comment: You need || part because read fails on the last line without EOF, so you need to exit loop only if `read` fails _and_ $LINE is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error you are getting is because your script is also processing the header of your file. An easy fix would be to skip lines that begin with a `#`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
   echo "No file found"
   exit 1
fi

## Use grep -v to print lines that don't match the pattern given. 
grep -v '^#' "$1" | 
while read -r LINE || [ -n "$LINE" ]; do
   name=$( echo "$LINE" | cut -d " " -f1,2)
   age=$( echo "$LINE" | cut -d " " -f9)
   echo "$name ----- $age"
   if [ "$age" -gt 30 ]; then
      echo "You got a discount"
   fi
done
```

However, since presumably you will also want to do stuff with your other columns, I would read all of them into variables directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
   echo "No file found"
   exit 1
fi

## read can take multiple values and splits the input line on whitespace
## automatically. Each field is assigned to one of the variables given.
## If there are more fields than variable names, the remaining fields
## are all assigned to the last variable.
grep -v '^#' "$1" | while read -r first last super powers weapons city enemy isout age; do
   echo "$first $last  ----- $age"
   if [ "$age" -gt 30 ]; then
      echo "You got a discount"
   fi
done
```

Comment: @terdon could you tell me what does `while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]]; do` do?
Is the `||` here mean Or? and does `[[ -n $LINE ]]` mean if next line exists?

Comment: @Unknown yes, the `||` means OR. The `[ -n ]` test checks if a variable is null (see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)), so that while loop will run as long as `$LINE` is set and not empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
   echo "No file found"
   exit 1
fi

exec < $1

while read -r LINE || [ -n "$LINE" ]; do
   name=$( echo "$LINE" | cut -d " " -f1,2)
   age=$( echo "$LINE" | cut -d " " -f9)
   echo "$name ----- $age"
   if [ "$age" -gt 30 ]; then
      echo "You got a discount"
   fi
done
```

Comment: ARGH! I take it all back, my apologies. I was thinking about the `[[ ]]`, not `[ ]`. I'll delete our previous comments since they are irrelevant and I was just being an idiot (I'm leaving this one so you don't think I'm deleting just so people can't see that I was being an idiot) :)

Comment: regarding quotes in echo line, what if name is not specified in the file and there is just space?

Comment: Do come into the chat room posted above, we try to avoid long comment threads. As I said, you're quite right that quotes are needed in `[ ]` (but not `[[ ]]` :) nevertheless, this doesn't solve the OP's problem unless you also filter out the `#` signs. Anyway, my downvote was indeed mistaken and I have now removed it.

Comment: Yes, I bit overreacted too, author had no sample file than I posted my answer that's why there is no grep. Sorry, can't spend any time on this now - so can't chat. Removed my downvote too.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f $1 ] ; 
then 
    sum=0
    echo "#FirstName LastName City Age" 
    while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]]; do 
       name=$( echo $LINE | cut -d " " -f1 -f2) 
       city=$( echo $LINE | cut -d " " -f3) 
       age=$( echo $LINE | cut -d " " -f9) 
       check=$( echo $amount | grep -c "[0-9]") 
       if [ $check -gt 0 ]; then 
         if [ $age -gt 30 ] ; then 
            echo "You get a discount" 
         fi 
       fi 
    done < $1 

else 
    echo "No file found" 
fi
```

Comment: You need || part because read fails on the last line without EOF, so you need to exit loop only if `read` fails _and_ $LINE is empty.

Comment: I removed the question you were asking here and converted it to a comment. While answering your own post is fine, please don't use answers to request more information.

Comment: @gena2x what about the `-n` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd read the line into a bash array:

```
if [[ -f $1 ]] ; then
    while read -ra line; do
        (( ${#line[@]} > 0 )) || continue  # skip empty lines
        name=${line[*]:0:2}
        age=${line[-1]}
        echo "$name ----- $age"
        if (( $age > 30 )); then
            echo "You get a discount"
        fi
    done < "$1"
else
    echo "No file found"
fi
```

```
#FirstName LastName ----- Age
Bruce Wayne ----- 31
You get a discount
Clark Kent ----- 32
You get a discount
Oliver Queen ----- 30
```

This is also not troubled by $age being a non-integer:

```
$ age=Age
$ [ $age -gt 30 ] && echo old || echo young
bash: [: Age: integer expression expected
young
$ (( $age > 30 )) && echo old || echo young
young
$ [[ $age -gt 30 ]] && echo old || echo young
young
```